# Microsoft-Graph: Creating Teams Tab not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I call the graph API to create a new tab in teams, I receive 201 (Created) from API but the tab never appears.

I am sending the following JSON (note it is accepted and I receive 201)

Group ID & Notebook ID are the correct GUIDS for the Group & Notebook I'm trying to add respectively.

OneNoteWebUrl is coming from the Notebook itself (I call GET to get the notebook and use it's .Links.OneNoteWebUrl.Href value)

I am following documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs

```
{
    "teamsApp@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/0d820ecd-def2-4297-adad-78056cde7c78",
    "displayName":"Criminal Case Notes",
    "configuration": {
        "contentUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/teams/TabContent?entityid=%7BentityId%7D&subentityid=%7BsubEntityId%7D&auth_upn=%7Bupn%7D&notebookSource=New&notebookSelfUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onenote.com%2Fapi%2Fv1.0%2FmyOrganization%2Fgroups%2F{GroupID}%2Fnotes%2Fnotebooks%2F{NotebookID}&oneNoteWebUrl={OneNoteWebUrl}&notebookName=My%20Notes",
        "removeUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/teams/TabRemove?entityid=%7BentityId%7D&subentityid=%7BsubEntityId%7D&auth_upn=%7Bupn%7D&notebookSource=New&notebookSelfUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onenote.com%2Fapi%2Fv1.0%2FmyOrganization%2Fgroups%2F{GroupID}%2Fnotes%2Fnotebooks%2F{NotebookID}&oneNoteWebUrl={OneNoteWebUrl}&notebookName=My%20Notes",
        "websiteUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/teams/TabRedirect?redirectUrl={OneNoteWebUrl}"
    }
}
```

I was expecting this to add a One Note tab but alas nothing ever appears in the general channel :(

Comment: I was under a time crunch and had to move on, I was unable to resolve this issue but discovered you can add a web tab and use the notebook's WebsiteUrl property as the href. This at least displays the web version of One Note inside of teams.